# SQLite for VBA: provider or standalone DLL?

Tags: sqlite, vba

I'm creating VBA Word and Excel templates and I'd like to store data in SQLite. I've seen a standalone DLL that doesn't require any kind of registration on the machine, but I'm not sure this is as robust as using, say, an ODBC or other provider.

What do you use for VBA and SQLite? Is the DLL worth using, or is it better to use a standard data access method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, it works great:

http://sqliteforexcel.codeplex.com/